# Maximum Tree Needed for Random Forest Modeling

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, information-theory

Given a data set of certain size (say $n \times p$), is there a theory talking about the maximum or upper bound of the number of trees (or with certain depth) needed to sufficiently fit the data in a way? Hope my question is explicit enough.